# Removing Element from Modal window (shop cart) by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

so I try to make some simple content of modal window as a shopping cart only using js, and there is a problem with delete of each item by "x" after I add them on the cart, I use event.target, but at that stage it gives me an error as "null", it is in the last row of the code. Dont be strict, its my first code :)
so each time I insert in cart

```
cartItems.innerHTML += `<div class="modal-items-flex ">
<div>
<h2> Item Price: ${itemPrice} </h2>
<h2 class="underscore">Item Name: ${itemTitle} </h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-item-delete">+</div>
</div>`

let removeButton = document.querySelector(".modal-item-delete");

removeButton.onclick=function(e){                               
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not attach a new event-listener to each item, but instead would delegate the event-handling to the parent, for example:

```
cartItems.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const btn = e.target.closest('.modal-item-delete');
  if (!btn) return;
  btn.parentElement.remove();
});
```

Comment: thanks, but for what  `if (!btn) return;` is here? it works without it aswell.

Comment: @AramHarutyunyan This line is a safe guard, because the line below will throw an error if you click on an element outside a delete-button, since then `btn` would be null.

Comment: ah, I hide the context of modal if the main close of modal window is closed, so there is no such risks, but anyway, lets have double guard, thanks.

Comment: @AramHarutyunyan The listener will trigger on every click inside  the `cartItems` element, including those not inside a delete-button, which means the call to `closest` will not find an element then, causing a type-error when trying to remove the parent of _null_. The code works without the guard, but is less safe and that may cause you head-aches down the line.